# Change setup file comment

Tags: version, inno-setup

I have built a Setup with InnoSetup. When I display the properties of the Setup.exe file in Windows Explorer, the first field is "Comments" and it says

> This installation was built with Inno Setup.

Since this is one of the first things a user will see on Windows XP (not shown on Windows 7 at all) when looking at the properties, I'd like to change it so that it looks less like InnoSetup but more like my program. However, I could not find a setting for it. How could I modify this text using InnoSetup?

I've already gone through all the `VersionInfo*` properties of the `[Setup]` category.

Comment: It comes from [`this resource`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/SetupLdrVersion.rc#L23).

Comment: @TLama: ok, that means it is really hard coded and cannot be changed. Do you know whether the order of items in the RC file is relevant? If it is relevant, I'd make a suggestion (pull request or whatever) to move `FileDescription` to the top. I'll definitely not start compiling and maintaining my own version of InnoSetup just for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is strictly forbidden and it is against Inno Setup license policy.

Please do not do this, Inno is free and you are taking credits from it!

Comment: It's more Windows 7 which takes the credits from InnoSetup, because the field is no longer displayed. Anyway, I don't want to take the credits, I just want the customer be aware that this is not InnoSetup which he's installing, it's my application.